# Google Data Studio Custom dimension showing incorrect data

Tags: google-analytics, looker-studio, custom-dimensions, data-studio-custom-visuals

I was trying to create a custom dimension that will take specific pages together for my GDS report.
I need to create a dimension out of 4 pages to calculate metrics for them.
Here's what I was trying to do/have tried:

```
CASE
WHEN Page = "www.link1" 
OR  Page = "www.link2"
OR  Page = "www.link3"
OR Page = "www.link4"
THEN 1
ELSE 0
END
```

I've also tried using `IN`

```
CASE
WHEN Page IN ("www.link1","www.link2","www.link3","www.link4")
THEN 1
ELSE 0
END
```

My formula gets accepted but it shows the wrong data.
My ultimate goal is to draw a time-series chart of date vs the sum of pageviews for the particular custom dimension of these 4 pages. I am totally clueless about where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Summary

One way it can be achieved is by applying a Filter to a Time Series chart:

### 1) [Time Series](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7059697) Chart

- ***Date Range Dimension***: `Date`
- ***Dimension***: `Date`
- ***Metric***: `Pageviews`

### 2) [Filter](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6291066)

```
Include Page In www.link1,www.link2,www.link3,www.link4
```

[Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/31c2ee91-43d8-4518-a219-71f8c9054d97) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image]